# .htaccess Redirect with Wordpress in a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am moving an old site to a new site. But the new site is built into Wordpress in a sub-folder.

IE: `http://domainA.com`
TO: `http://domainB.com/wordpress/`

The Problem that i'm having is the NEWS part of the site. 
So basically I have a URL that is,

```
http://domainA.com/article/post-title-url-slug/
```

Which needs to now go to

```
http://domainB.com/*wordpress*/post-title-url-slug/
```

Where *wordpress* is the ROOT installation.

Hope this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated, I haven't been able to find a solution on SO yet....

**EDIT** - FOLDER STRUCTURE

/Root (APP)

/Root/careers/ *(careers === wordpress install, wp-content...etc)*

The HTACCESS For /careers/ IS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /careers/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /careers/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have removed the BASE category in the URL, so my URLS would be like.

http://www.example.com/**careers**/[**category**-title]

But what I need to setup now is, when they click on a SINGLE POST, it goes to a URL like this.

http://www.example.com/**article**/[**post**-title]

Answer (score 2):

That's a just simple 301 rewrite. This code goes in the `.htaccess` in the root of `domainA.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah this is something that I had tried, but for some reason it continues to route to my 'root' domain.  (ie: domainA.com)....  it's not taking on the redirect....

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try it. Also can you post your current rules for domainA.com in the question.

Comment: Hey, I just updated my question to be a lot more descriptive, I think it makes sense more now, let me know your thoughts...

Comment: Now you original requirement doesn't seem to make sense with what you just posted. You said you needed `article/post-title-url-slug/` to go to `careers/post-title-url-slug/`. Which is what the rule I posted does. But now you're saying something different about a post??

Comment: Yeah I think I screwed my question when I asked it looking back. The "edited" content is more accurate, sorry...